# For what we need Account => MY APPLICATIONS

Tags: customer-account

Not once in practice not see that this functionality is used, what it is?

Comment: It's for applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the second Google result:

oAuth integration

This is useful for when you would like to have users to log in to your shop with their Twitter or Facebook credentials and for other apps to be able to access your Magento account. After approval by the customer, Magento and the 3rd party webapplication can exchange data. This might give you the option to retrieve the sex and home location when someone connects through Facebook.

Customers can manage the applications under the new My Account > My Applications tab.